# Unable to apply WHERE/AND on MySQL table with 2 columns on MAMP

Tags: mysql, mamp

I thought I had a very simple query to perform, but I can't seem to make it work.

I have this table with 2 columns:

```
version_id       trim_id
    1               15
    1               25
    1               28
    1               30
    1               35
    2               12
    2               25
    2               33
    2               48
    3               11
    3               25
    3               30
    3               32
```

I am trying to get any version-id's that have say a sub-set of trim_id's. Let's say all version_id's that have trim_id's 25 and 30. My obvious attempt was :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE trim_id=25 AND trim_id=30
```

I was expecting to have version_id 1 and 3 as a result, but instead I get nothing.

I am working with the latest version of MAMP, which has some odd behavior, like in this case it just tells me its 'LOADING' and never gives me an error message or something. But that's normally the case when there is no data to return.

This is InnoDB, if that helps.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query does not work because you are using `AND` and the `trim_id` cannot have two different values at the same time, so you need to apply [Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) to get the result.

You will need to use something similar to the following:

```
SELECT version_id
FROM yourtable 
WHERE trim_id in (25, 30)
group by version_id
having count(distinct trim_id) = 2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c91b7/3).

This will return the `version_id` values that have both `25` and `30`.  Then if you wanted to include additional columns in the final result, you can expand the query to:

```
select t1.version_id, t1.trim_id
from yourtable t1
where exists (SELECT t2.version_id
              FROM yourtable  t2
              WHERE t2.trim_id in (25, 30)
                and t1.version_id = t2.version_id
              group by t2.version_id
              having count(distinct t2.trim_id) = 2);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c91b7/8)

Comment: Thanks a lot, bluefeet. That did the trick! I suspected that AND was not applicable, but it would take me generations to arrive to the Relational Division thing. You saved me a lot of time. 1000 points to you if I could.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE trim_id IN(25,30)
```

Comment: Thanks Raheel, but that is not what I am looking for. The result for your query would be version_id's 1,2,3, because all have either 25 or 30. Version_id 2 does have 25 but not 30. I need to have version_id's that have BOTH 25 and 30. Which in the example are version_id's 1 and 3.